# How to use Outlook's AdvancedSerach to find expiring e-mail via assigned server policy

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-2010

I am attempting to find all expiring e-mails via Advanced Search method provided below.  Optimistically, I hoped that their searches [in articles such as this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2457735), and [this](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/158/t/150622.aspx) which suggests using 'expires:<=the next month' would do the trick, but it does not.

```
string filter = String.Format("expires:<=next month");
string scope = "'" + inboxFolder.FolderPath + "'";
Outlook.Search search = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AdvancedSearch(scope, filter, true, "Expiring Retention Policy Mail");
```

When attmepting to run the above code, I receive the error *'the operation failed'*

Here is the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
to the Advanced Search Query provided by Microsoft which has no mention of expiration policy.  **Does anybody know the Advanced Search Query equivalent to the expires:<=next month feature?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it on a reference sheet on MSDN for schemas [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/ms875130%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx):

```
DateTime expirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
string expiresFilter = String.Format("urn:schemas:mailheader:expires>'{0}' AND urn:schemas:mailheader:expires<'{0}'", DateTime.Now, expirationDate);
string scope = "'" + inboxFolder.FolderPath + "'";
Outlook.Search search = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AdvancedSearch(scope, expiresFilter, true, "Expiring Retention Policy Mail");
```